# Can Ethereum prevent secondary market sales?

Tags: tokens

The app:  If you beat a videogame you get a `win-token-v1` and the first 100 get discord access.  The rest of the people who beat the game get `win-token-v2` -- which has no value, except `win-token-v2` can be traded and burned (eg. trade `1 ETH` + `win-token-v2` for `win-token-v1`) on one-and-only-one smart-contract -- because max discord users is 100 and I need to verify that you beat the game.

Can it be set up so that users can only trade `win-token-v1` for `win-token-v2` on my (and no one elses) smart-contract? ie. **can we prevent secondary market sales?**  The objective: no one who hasn't beaten the game is allowed into the discord, but secondary market sales defeat the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since `win-token-v1` and `win-token-v2` are most probably ERC-721 tokens (NFTs), they manage their own ledger and able to allow `transferFrom` to be executed from a specific `msg.sender`, that will be your smart contract.

So essentially, you limit the `transfer` and `transferFrom` to work only for whitelisted address/es.

Check out [StackOS's implementation](https://polygonscan.com/address/0xd9a26c042b51ec5d54222e17629e4c4b4be6a8dd#code) for their node NFT, they allow trading to be done only through their marketplace, charging royalties from the trade -

```
    function _transfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) 
        internal 
        override(ERC721) 
        onlyWhitelisted 
    {
        super._transfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }
```

they override Openzeppelin's `_transfer` and added `onlyWhitelisted` modifier, this limits calls to be done from chosen addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can easily be done, by making the smart contract store which adresses have which tokens. This is standard for e.g. ERC20 tokens. For example, if you own USDT, you don't actually have this in your ETH account, the USDT contract just contains a large "database" that stores the fact that there are x amount of USDT tokens associated with your adres. No one but the smart contract itself can change this data (if the contract is set up correctly), so no one can buy or sell USDT without going through the contract.

See e.g. this: https://www.toptal.com/ethereum/create-erc20-token-tutorial for an example implementation.